# Can a Kernel Mode Driver Prevent a Windows System from Booting?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, boot, bios

I have recently been attempting to create a GPIO Driver for SBC's using an Intel chipset that run Windows 8.1 and have begun testing it on an actual system. After loading the Driver and updating the Intel chipset I am using, the system appears to hang after loading the BIOS. Unfortunately, this disables my mouse, keyboard, and video, preventing me from entering BIOS or the boot manager.

While it is possible that the chipset update caused the system to become unbootable, it is highly unlikely considering we use that update for our other SBC's running the same chipset.

So my question: Is it possible for a Windows Kernel Mode driver to prevent a system from booting up past BIOS/POST?

I appreciate the help, since, clearly, I am no expert on this topic.

Comment: To answer your question, yes. A driver bug can hide anything.

Comment: Does your driver load during boot (start ==0)? If so, then it can cause that. If no, then some other driver or hardware issue is causing that. You may want to try different booting options (pressing F8) especially debug/boot logging.

Comment: @Rohan That's exactly what I was looking for. It was just a simple question of if it was possible (mainly so I don't have to spend time debugging the wrong area). Since my driver was the source of the problem, I figured out that I needed add "\\DosDevices\\..." to a file path I am calling since it loads the driver on boot, or it crashes upon trying to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your driver is being loaded at boot time it can prevent the booting of the OS and it will end up in BSOD(Blue screen of death) error with related bug check.

According to bugcheck displayed  by the OS you can resolve the issues with your driver.

Or sometimes if its not giving any error and just hangs you can use WinDbg to check the bugcheck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the error control of the driver service. Boot time drivers can also fail at any point. There is nothing special about the failure happening during boot. Instead, what is relevant under this scenario depends more on the ErrorControl value of the driver service which specifies how to proceed if it fails to load or initialize properly. A value of 3 (critical) would reboot the system to LKGC. Same rules apply to a win32 servic as well..